# I am not able to index into a 1x2 numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I am trying to index into initial, referenced by `last_guess`. However, I am still getting the index error below.

```
i = np.array([5., 0.])
def particle_filter(initial, uncertainty, landmarks, n, A, sigma):
     k = float(n)
    last_guess = initial
    print(type(last_guess))
    weights = np.ones(n)
    weights = weights / k
    mean_and_vars = np.empty((n, 2))

# Create the new particles
    for i in range(1, n):
            for i in range(1, n):
    x = last_guess[0]
    y = last_guess[1]
    new_x_range = np.array([x - k/2, x + k/2])
    new_y_range = np.array([y - k/2, y + k/2])

    particles = create_uniform_particles(new_x_range, new_y_range, n)
    # Calculate the new weights of each particle
    landmark = np.array([landmarks[i][0], landmarks[i][1]])
    predict_2d(particles, uncertainty, A)
    update(particles, weights, landmark, sigma)

    # Store the mean and variance from these results
    mean_and_vars[i] = estimate(particles, weights)
    last_guess = mean_and_vars[i][0]
    particles = create_uniform_particles(new_x_range, new_y_range, n)
    # Calculate the new weights of each particle
    landmark = np.array([landmarks[i][0], landmarks[i][1]])
    predict_2d(particles, uncertainty, A)
    update(particles, weights, landmark, sigma)

    # Store the mean and variance from these results
    mean_and_vars[i] = estimate(particles, weights)
    last_guess = mean_and_vars[i][0]
```

Output:

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[5. 2.]
5.631195079155192
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/scottdayton/PycharmProjects/Uncertainty Research/particle.py", line 97, in 
particle_filter(i, sigma, obs, n, trans, sigma0)
File "/Users/scottdayton/PycharmProjects/Uncertainty Research/particle.py", line 58, in particle_filter
x = last_guess[0]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: You are overwriting the `new_x_range` everytime. Any reason for putting it in a `for` loop. Also, what is the value of `initial` being passed to the function? Is it the same array that you have provided?

Comment: I am overwriting the new_x_range because I have more steps after I create the particles, where I give each particle a weight based off of its distance from a certain landmark, and I have to loop through all of the landmarks, so I use a for loop. The value being passed into initial is the one above the function, yes. I want to overwrite the new_x_range everytime.

Comment: first use `print()` and `print( type() )` to see what you have in variables in line which makes problem. AND check what you use when you run `particle_filter(init, ....)` because you can use something different then external `initial` in place of `init`. Internal `initial` doesn't means external `initial` - and your `init` doesn't have to be your external `initial`

Comment: Somehow `last_guess` is changed. It may start as `initial`, the (2,) shape array.  Is the more code in this loop?

Comment: It is hard to help when give pieces of code that we cannot run and reproduce your error.  This is the 3rd question with the same problem!

Comment: I have used print statements on last_guess. Printing its type is 'numpy.ndarray'. Printing last_guess yields [5.  0.], what I assign to 'initial' and it changes accordingly when I change 'initial'.

Comment: I dont understand. Where is ` x = last_guess[0]` in the snippet? That's where the error is, right? Also, print the shape of `last_guess` just before the line on which you have the error. That would make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was reassigning last_guess with a singular value, as mean_and_vars[i][0] was just one floating point value. I apologize for wasting time, as I thought the error was coming solely from the beginning of the code. To hpaulj, your frustration is justified. I apologize, I was in a panic and time crunch to figure this out and did not step back and realize that I was wrong in where I thought the problem was. Thank you all for your input. I will be better in the future.